# Proving the recurrence relation $xL_n'(x) = n l_n(x) - n L_{n-1}(x)$

Tags: recurrence-relations

How can I prove the following recurrence relation for [Laguerre polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaguerrePolynomial.html) eqn $(11)$.
$$xL_n'(x) = n L_n(x) - n L_{n-1}(x)$$
I managed to show that the following which seems to be [true](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%20%20n%20LaguerreL%5Bn,%20x%5D%20%2b%20%28n%20-%20x%29%20D%5BLaguerreL%5Bn,%20x%5D,%20%7Bx,%201%7D%5D%20-%20%20%20%20%20n%20D%5BLaguerreL%5Bn%20-%201,%20x%5D,%20%7Bx,%201%7D%5D,%20%7Bn,%201,%205%7D%5D). I put all things on one side and this yields zero.
$$(x-n) L_n'(x) = n L_n(x) - nL_{n-1}(x) $$
Mathematica code
`Simplify[Table[
  n LaguerreL[n, x] + (n - x) D[LaguerreL[n, x], {x, 1}] - 
   n D[LaguerreL[n - 1, x], {x, 1}], {n, 1, 5}]]`

This has been bugging me for a while. Did I do anything wrong or that recurrence relation on math-world site is wrong?

**Added::**  my equation was $\displaystyle (x-n) L_n'(x) = n L_n(x) - nL_{n-1}'(x) $
Now I need to show $\displaystyle L_n'(x) - L_{n-1}'(x) = -L_{n-1}(x)$ holds, and [that it does](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B-D%5BLaguerreL%5Bn,%20x%5D,%20%7Bx,%201%7D%5D%20%2b%20LaguerreL%5Bn,%20x%5D%20%2b%20%20%20%20%20D%5BLaguerreL%5Bn%20%2b%201,%20x%5D,%20%7Bx,%201%7D%5D,%20%7Bn,%201,%205%7D%5D), can be shown via differentiating generating function w.r.t. $t$.

Comment: First: There is a small typo in your equation, it should be $xL_n'(x) = n L_n(x) - n L_{n-1}(x)$. Second and more important: your link and the code expresse $L_n$ in terms of $L_n'$ and $L_{n-1}'$ and **not** $L_n'$ in terms of $L_n$ and $L_{n-1}$!

Comment: @gammatester thanks, then I need to show $ L_n'(x) - L_{n-1}'(x) = L_{n-1}(x)$

Comment: There is a sign error, it should be 
$\quad L_n'(x)−L_{n−1}'(x) = - L_{n−1}'(x), \quad$ see e.g. Lebedev, Special Functions (4.18.2)

Comment: @gammatester yes yes sorry again :((

Comment: @gammatester you could have posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove $L_n'(x) - L_{n-1}'(x) = -L_{n-1}(x).\quad $ We have the recurrence formula
$$  n L_n(x) = (2n-1-x) L_{n-1}(x) - (n-1)L_{n-2}(x) $$
and therefore
$$ -xL_{n-1}(x) = n L_n(x) - (2n-1) L_{n-1}(x) + (n-1)L_{n-2}(x) $$
Then we use 
$$x L_n'(x) = n L_n(x) - n L_{n-1}(x)$$
or rewritten:
$$ L_n'(x) = \frac{ n L_n(x) - n L_{n-1}(x)}{x}$$
And the same or for $(n-1)$
$$ L_{n-1}'(x) = \frac{ (n-1) L_{n-1}(x) - (n-1) L_{n-2}(x)}{x}$$
Subtracting the last two gives
$$ L_n'(x)  - L_{n-1}'(x)= \frac{ n L_n(x) - n L_{n-1}(x) - (n-1)L_{n-1}(x) + (n-1)L_{n-2}(x)}{x}$$

$$ L_n'(x)  - L_{n-1}'(x)= \frac{ n L_n(x) - (2n-1) L_{n-1}(x) + (n-1)L_{n-2}(x)}{x}$$
Now substitute the rewritten recurrence formula:

$$ L_n'(x)  - L_{n-1}'(x)= \frac{ -x L_{n-1}(x)}{x} = -L_{n-1}(x)$$